# getting cp progress in machine readable format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://bucketname/foo.txt
```

shows output like this:

```
Completed 1.2 MiB/179.5 MiB (116.0 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining
```

It's somewhat ephemeral though.  The line continues to update.  Even if I redirect it into another file it can't be read by another program.

Is there a way I can funnel the continually changing output of that command into a file s.t. that I can read from it and parse it to get progress etc?

Comment: The CLI `aws` is designed for humans to read. However, the output can be parsed. Each line is terminated with `\r` (carriage return). Process that as the line terminator for some of the lines. Others will be terminated with `\n` (line feed). However, the best technique is to write your own program and process status events.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hmm, so, if I redirect the command above to a file "aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://bucketname/foo.txt > /tmp/tmpfile 2>&1" - and then tail or cat that file while the aws cp is still running... I see a lot of blank lines and then finally: "upload: ./foo.txt to s3://bucketname/foo.txt" - I never see the progress messages

Comment: Use a binary editor and look at the program output (written to a file). Then you will understand the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I used curl to post data to AWS and parsed the output from curl which is pretty straightforward.